# Why does time in UTC look different depending on how it is created

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

When I insert it as default with SQLAlchemy

```
time_now = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False,
                        default=datetime.now(timezone.utc),)
```

I get `2021-07-02 13:31:17.810926` and when I insert it with

```
time_now = datetime.now(timezone.utc))
CONNECTION.execute(
        '''INSERT INTO time_now (time_now) VALUES(?)''', (time_now))
CONNECTION.commit()
```

I get `2021-07-02 13:44:36.691583+00:00`, this one includes the offset (which is wrong btw)

Why are they behaving differently?

And why do they not indicate it is UTC with a Z?

Comment: The first one is calculated _once_ when you create the table - the `default=...` is evaluated just once at that time. The second one is being calculated when you execute each query.

Comment: Why do you say that the offset is “wrong”, when you explicitly said to use UTC?